# jsGrid : Adding a new row using json data

Tags: jsgrid

```
// insert item 
$("#grid").jsGrid("insertItem", { Name: "John", Age: 25, Country: 2 }).done(function() { console.log("insertion completed"); });
```

I did the same as specified above. but row is inserting at the bottom not at the top. Row should be inserted at the top when I write the above snippet of code for inserting json data... Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Please go through documentation before asking question. 
In your grid config add the below.

```
insertRowLocation: "top"
```

Taken from [https://github.com/tabalinas/jsgrid/issues/796][1]

Comment: i am no longer see insertRowLocation section on the documentation.

Comment: @AdiPrasetyo my comment was done more than three years back, at that time it was valid answer. Right now it is possible that in due time the method/field/option might have been deprecated or removed.